# Bootstrap4 align-self-baseline doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Here I'm trying to stick tag buttons to the `baseline` of the parent `div`. If it's not an appropriate method to do this, could you please suggest other one?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-4">
            <div class="card bg-light">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 blog-card-doc">
                            <div class="row d-flex ">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <a class="h3" href="#">Blog Post</a>
                                    <p>
                                        <i class="small">2018-03-05</i>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt nulla nec mi aliquet, commodo laoreet nisi placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam id finibus est.</p>
                                </div>
                                <footer class="col-md-12 blog-card-tags align-self-baseline">
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" href="#">blog-tag</a>
                                    </div>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img height="300" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="300">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a height issue. The `row` should be `height:100%`. Use `align-self-end` for the bottom of the column, relative to the adjacent column. Use `align-self-end` baseline for the cross-axis relative to the adjacent column.

https://www.codeply.com/go/k372k4H7Ze

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-4">
            <div class="card bg-light">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row h-100">
                        <div class="col-md-7 blog-card-doc">
                            <div class="row h-100">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <a class="h3" href="#">Blog Post</a>
                                    <p>
                                        <i class="small">2018-03-05</i>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt nulla nec mi aliquet, commodo laoreet nisi placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam id finibus est.</p>
                                </div>
                                <footer class="col-md-12 blog-card-tags align-self-end">
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" href="#">blog-tag</a>
                                    </div>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img height="300" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" width="300">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```